# Why does /usr/bin/timeout kill the entire pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a program that indefinitely generates output. I want to sample that output for a second and pipe into gzip. I'm using `timeout` util to limit the execution but the problem is that `gzip` gets killed as well.

E.g.:

```
$ /usr/bin/timeout 1 bash -c "echo asdf; sleep 5" | gzip > /tmp/foo.gz; ls -lah /tmp/foo.gz 
Terminated
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haizaar haizaar 0 Jul 22 15:05 /tmp/foo.gz
```

You see, the gzip command is `Terminated` and hence its output results in an empty file (due to the lost buffers)

**I don't understand how `timeout` manages to kill a process that reads its stdout; and how to fix it.**
Even wrapping the whole thing in another `bash` results the same:

```
$ bash -c '/usr/bin/timeout 1 bash -c "echo asdf; sleep 5"' | gzip > /tmp/foo.gz; ls -lah /tmp/foo.gz
Terminated
-rw-rw-r-- 1 haizaar haizaar 0 Jul 22 15:30 /tmp/foo.gz
```

I can prepend `timeout` with `setsid` and then it works which makes me think it's somehow related to process groups being mixed up but it's hard to accept the fact that the current situation is "by design" because it makes `timeout` command very tricky to use with shell pipes.

Environemnt:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ timeout --version
timeout (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Padraig Brady.
```

**UPDATE**
KamilCuk was spot on with his strace analysis. It also explains while wrapping `timeout` in another `bash` doesn't help either - it seems like bash has an optimization where if it has only command to run it doesn't `fork`s but rather `exec`s replacing itself.
But if you add another command into the wrapping `bash` then it will fork thus creating a new process group and hence limiting the blast radius of the `timeout` command. I.e.

```
bash -c 'true; /usr/bin/timeout 1 bash -c "echo asdf; sleep 5"' | gzip > /tmp/foo.gz
```

(note the leading `true`)

I still think using `timeout` in pipelines is a black magic but that's another story.

Comment: Moreover, behavior differs between interactive and non-interactive shell - `bash -ic "timeout 1 sh -c 'echo asdf ; sleep 5' | { sleep 2; echo 123; }"` vs `bash -c "timeout 1 sh -c 'echo asdf ; sleep 5' | { sleep 2; echo 123; }"`. From short `strace` looks like the inner `bash` process inside `timeout` kills the entire process group.

Comment: timeout wouldn't be much use if it didn't kill all the processes spawned by the first  command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ strace -ff -e trace=setpgid,kill,exit_group,exit,execve,wait4 bash --norc --noprofile -ic "timeout -v 1 bash --norc --noprofile -c 'echo asdf ; sleep 5' | { sleep 2; echo 123; }" 
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "--norc", "--noprofile", "-ic", "timeout -v 1 bash --norc --nopro"...], 0x7ffeb8ef7ef8 /* 76 vars */) = 0
setpgid(0, 28995)                       = 0
strace: Process 28996 attached
[pid 28995] setpgid(28996, 28996)       = 0
[pid 28996] setpgid(28996, 28996)       = 0
strace: Process 28997 attached
[pid 28995] setpgid(28997, 28996)       = 0
[pid 28995] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 28997] setpgid(28997, 28996)       = 0
[pid 28996] execve("/usr/bin/timeout", ["timeout", "-v", "1", "bash", "--norc", "--noprofile", "-c", "echo asdf ; sleep 5"], 0x560da0ff57e0 /* 76 vars */strace: Process 28998 attached
) = 0
[pid 28997] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 28998] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "2"], 0x560da0ff57e0 /* 76 vars */) = 0
[pid 28996] setpgid(0, 0)               = 0
strace: Process 28999 attached
[pid 28996] wait4(28999, 0x7ffd7eb5e96c, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
[pid 28999] execve("/usr/local/bin/bash", ["bash", "--norc", "--noprofile", "-c", "echo asdf ; sleep 5"], 0x7ffd7eb5ec10 /* 76 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 28999] execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "--norc", "--noprofile", "-c", "echo asdf ; sleep 5"], 0x7ffd7eb5ec10 /* 76 vars */) = 0
[pid 28999] execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "5"], 0x55a84be27270 /* 76 vars */) = 0
[pid 28996] --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_TIMER, si_timerid=0, si_overrun=0, si_int=0, si_ptr=NULL} ---
timeout: sending signal TERM to command ‘bash’
[pid 28996] kill(28999, SIGTERM)        = 0
[pid 28999] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=28996, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 28996] kill(0, SIGTERM <unfinished ...>
[pid 28997] <... wait4 resumed>0x7ffc114a9600, 0, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid 28996] <... kill resumed>)         = 0
[pid 28999] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid 28998] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=28996, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 28997] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=28996, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 28996] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=28996, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 28996] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=28999, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 28997] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid 28995] <... wait4 resumed>[{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGTERM}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 28997
[pid 28998] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid 28995] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 28996] kill(28999, SIGCONT)        = 0
[pid 28996] kill(0, SIGCONT)            = 0
[pid 28996] --- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=28996, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 28996] wait4(28999, [{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGTERM}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 28999
[pid 28996] exit_group(124)             = ?
[pid 28996] +++ exited with 124 +++
<... wait4 resumed>[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 124}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 28996
Terminated
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=28997, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7ffc114a9710, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
setpgid(0, 28992)                       = 0
exit_group(143)                         = ?
+++ exited with 143 +++
```

So what happens is that `timeout` tries to be smart and kills the whole process group. From what I understand, it happens that:

- bash creates a process group for the pipeline `setpgid(28996, 28996)`
- timeout starts a process also in the same group `setpgid(0, 0)`
- after the timeout `timeout` kills the whole process group `kill(0, SIGTERM <unfinished ...>`
- because all pipeline processes are in the same process group, all are killed.

You can make bash start a new process group for the left side with a command grouping `{ ... }`.

You could use `timeout --foreground`, however then `timeout` will *only* kill the foreground process. So while `bash` will die, `gzip` process will still wait on `sleep 5` running in the background, because it will have open `stdin` to it.

*Guessing* (also from [commit message](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/4d90d29899917ec16ea5806a0456501e5e948960)) I think this could be the intention so that `timeout` can kill the whole pipeline just as-if it would be a magic shell built-in.

Also, the behavior differs between job control enabled and disabled, so differs between interactive and non-interactive shells.

Comment: Nice resume. I will delete my answer, not immediately as its comments may be useful to dig.

Comment: You said "You can use `timeout --foreground` to remedy the situation". Strangely, `/usr/bin/timeout --foreground 1 bash -c "echo asdf; sleep 5" | gzip > /tmp/foo.gz; ls -l /tmp/foo.gz` takes 5 seconds without terminating.

Comment: @k314159 `timeout --foreground 1 sleep 5 | cat` would work. But with `timeout --foreground 1 bash -c "echo asdf; sleep 5"` the `sleep` is a child of `bash` and `man timeout` states for `--foreground` that "*children of COMMAND will not be timed out*".

Comment: It seems directly related to how the shell groups the processes. With `timeout -v 1 sleep 10 | { trap "{ echo TRM; }" TERM;  sleep 2; echo "aa" ; }` => duration 1sec and got TERM. With the same but using `bash <<EOF` and `timeout -v 1 sleep 10 | { trap "{ echo TRM; }" TERM;  sleep 2; echo "aa" ; }` then `EOF` => duration 2 sec and no TERM.

Comment: I guess you can add in the answer that this behavior seems strictly linked with a direct execution in a interactive shell. The same command in a shell script or through indirections works as expected. With strace, i see two pipe creations for two subshells with partial _abnormal_ close on the first pipe and pid grouping of the both subshell  for the direct execution, and juste one pipe and only the first subshell grouped through a shell script execution.  Same behavior for ksh and zsh.

Comment: Like dash, csh works as expected. The issue seems **not limited to `timeout`**, as we can observe the exact same behavior with `kill -64 -$$ | { trap "{ echo USR; }" 64; echo "aa"; }`. Works as expected in a shell, but trigger USR on direct execution... So it seems the issue relates to how bash, zsh and ksh handle pgid on pipe command in direct execution.

Comment: After multiple tests, it seems it depends on a random condition... With bash, some consoles trigger the USR and others don't... More, dash and csh seems also subjects to that...

Comment: Curiously, on every bash console, `bash -c 'kill -64 -$$;' | { trap "{ echo USR; }" 64;  sleep 2; echo "aa" ; }` trigger the USR always...  Contrary to ksh where only `kill -64 -$$ | { trap "{ echo USR; }" 64; echo "aa"; }` triggers it, `ksh -c 'kill -64 -$$;' | { trap "{ echo USR; }" 64;  sleep 2; echo "aa" ; }` **never trigger it**. I'm a little at loss...